# Move text input down in div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div with two things inside, a header and an input of type `text`. For the header I made its `position` `relative`, then set its `top` to `10%` which moved it down as I expected. However when I try do the same with the input box it's not being moved down, as shown here:

[image: Div]

The elements and their css are all created using jQuery since this is a userscript for a game. Here is that part of the code:

```
   var prompt = document.createElement('h1');
   $(prompt).css({'color':'#E6E6FA', 'font-family':'Palatino Linotype', 'position':'relative', 'top':'10%'}).text('Enter your TagPro name');
   var nameField = document.createElement('input');
   $(nameField).attr({'id':'nameField', 'type':'text'}).css({'position':'relative','top':'60%','font-size':'20px'});
   $(nameDiv).append(prompt, nameField);
```

As seen, the `position` of both elements are `relative`, but only the header seems to be moving down. Can someone please help me understand why this is?

Comment: why not create classes for these elements to be held in the style sheet and then when you create them - you add the class. Creating elements with inline styling is not the best approach IMO - and also - the text related to the input should be its label - not a h1

Comment: any reason why you are doing this with jQuery and not just css ? Add a jsfiddle so we can help better.

Comment: It's a script that can only use 1 js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your input element is an inline element. Add `display: block` to its CSS.

```
$(nameField)
  .attr({'id':'nameField', 'type':'text'})
  .css({'display':'block','position':'relative','top':'60%','font-size':'20px'});
```

And note that `position: relative` will mean the `top` that you set is relative to where the element would otherwise have been placed, not relative to the top edge of its container - if you want the input to be 60% of the way down the containing div you'd need to change it to `position: absolute`.

Comment: Nice, also I'd do it using `$("</>",{})` like http://jsbin.com/gifuzi/1/edit?html,css,js,output